# Javascript/Canvas: Moving and scaling rectangle... works but

Tags: javascript, canvas, resize, scale, mousemove

I maked a sample https://jsfiddle.net/movxyrrv/ and [GIF Animation problem](https://im3.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-3-cabe85958a.gif). Works until I change the size (square), after changing the size of the square the mouse move faster than the square. How can i fix it?

html

```
<canvas oncontextmenu="return false;" id="test" width="480" height="380"></canvas>
<div id="text">Press right mouse button to change scale 0.5 and see the problem</div>
```

javascript

```
var ctx = test.getContext('2d');
var obj = { x:100,y: 100,width: 100,height: 100}
var mouse = {x:0, y:0, width:10, height:10};

// change zoom to 0.5 
var zoom = 1;
var move = {startX: 0, startY: 0, click: false}; 

setInterval(function(){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,test.width,test.height);
    ctx.save();
    ctx.scale(zoom,zoom);
    ctx.fillRect(obj.x,obj.y,obj.width,obj.height);
    ctx.restore();
    if(move.click){
        obj.x = mouse.x - move.startX;
        obj.y = mouse.y - move.startY;
    }
},1000/60);

function collision(obj1,obj2){
    if(obj1.x*zoom < obj2.x + obj2.width &&
   (obj1.x + obj1.width)*zoom > obj2.x &&
   obj1.y *zoom < obj2.y + obj2.height &&
   (obj1.height + obj1.y)*zoom > obj2.y){
            return true;
    }
}

window.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e){
    if(collision(obj,mouse)){
        move.click = true;
        move.startX = e.pageX - obj.x;
        move.startY = e.pageY - obj.y;
    }

  if(e.which==3 || e.which==2){
    zoom=0.5;
  }
}, false);

window.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e){
    move.click = false;
}, false);

window.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e){
    mouse.x = e.pageX;
    mouse.y = e.pageY;
}, false);
```

Comment: Hello! I think you'd find the error if you organized your code better. Now, you don't really know where and how to look for it

Comment: The issue is that you're using `scale` to scale your canvas, but you're not scaling the mouse distances accordingly. Essentially, when setting `obj.x` and `obj.y`, you'll have to divide by the `zoom` factor.

Comment: Indeed: https://jsfiddle.net/afcfux7w/

Comment: Oh... Thanks God for suggestion and update.